# EOF error filemaker - whats causing this issue

Tags: email, eof, filemaker

I'm using 360works plugin on filemaker to send a html email and its throwing a 'EOF error'. Does anyone know what this error is / what the problem could be with?

Comment: EOF usually means End of File. Have you reached the end of the file and are continuing to read it?

Comment: Is this likely to be within the script I've created to send the email or within the software itself?

Comment: Edit your answer and post the script you have written and people will be able to help